# DEPRECATED USAGE: Forwarding SINGULARITYENV_TMP as environment variable will not be supported (Nextflow)

Tags: linux, conda, environment, singularity-container, nextflow

I have a nextflow workflow using a singularity .sif file for one of the processes.

After running my workflow I saw in the logs the following message:

```
WARNING: DEPRECATED USAGE: Forwarding SINGULARITYENV_TMP as environment variable will not be supported in the future, use APPTAINERENV_TMP instead 
WARNING: DEPRECATED USAGE: Forwarding SINGULARITYENV_TMPDIR as environment variable will not be supported in the future, use APPTAINERENV_TMPDIR instead 
WARNING: DEPRECATED USAGE: Forwarding SINGULARITYENV_NXF_DEBUG as environment variable will not be supported in the future, use APPTAINERENV_NXF_DEBUG instead
```

My nextflow.config looks like this

```
singularity {
    enabled = true
    autoMounts = true
}

conda {
    conda = './env.yml'
    enabled = true
}

//Wynton process Config
process {
    executor = "sge"
    scratch = true
    stageInMode = "copy"
    stageOUtMode="move"
    errorStrategy = "retry"
    clusterOptions = "-S /bin/bash -o job.log -e job.err"

    withName: PROCESS_1 {
        conda = './env.yml'

    withName: SINGULARITY_PROGRAM {
        container = 'program.sif'
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Singularity was renamed to Apptainer when the project moved to the Linux Foundation. All `$SINGULARITYENV_*` environment variables have been deprecated and will be removed in later releases of Apptainer. Note that Apptainer will warn you when it sees SINGULARITYENV environment variables. I suspect you get these warnings because your `singularity` is probably a symlink to `apptainer`, which is the case when installing version [1.1.3](https://github.com/apptainer/apptainer/releases/tag/v1.1.3) for example.

Nextflow support for the Apptainer container engine was added in version [22.11.0-edge](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/releases/tag/v22.11.0-edge) just six days ago. This edge release now has the following command line option:

```
    -with-apptainer
       Enable process execution in a Apptainer container
```

To enable it in the Nextflow config, add to (or replace the `singularity` block with) your Nextflow [config](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html) the following:

```
apptainer {
    enabled = true
    autoMounts = true
}
```

And run your workflow using the latest release:

```
NXF_VER=22.11.0-edge nextflow run
```